# Pareto-optimal shortest paths

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

Given a directed graph on the nodes `0, 1, ..n`, where each edge has *two* non-negative integer costs, return the set of all possible [Pareto Optimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) path costs between node `0` and node `n`.

These are the costs of paths for which you cannot decrease the first component of the cost without increasing the second component, and conversely.

In the examples, I have given the input as a dictionary of edge costs, but you could also take a matrix of edge costs, or a list of edges with their corresponding costs.

Examples:

```
{(0, 1): (1, 4), (1, 2): (4, 2), (0, 2): (2, 1)} -> [(2, 1)]

{(0, 1): (2, 2), (2, 3): (4, 2), (0, 2): (3, 1), 
 (0, 3): (1, 4)} -> [(1, 4), (7, 3)]


{(1, 4): (2, 4), (2, 3): (2, 1), (1, 2): (3, 1), 
 (3, 4): (4, 1), (0, 1): (2, 2), (2, 4): (1, 4),
 (0, 2): (1, 3)} -> [(4, 6), (2, 7), (7, 5)]

{(0, 3): (2, 4), (3, 5): (2, 4), (0, 1): (1, 1), 
 (1, 4): (4, 1), (1, 2): (2, 1), (3, 4): (1, 1),
 (1, 3): (2, 2), (4, 5): (4, 2)} -> [(4, 8), (9, 4), (5, 7), (8, 6)]

{(1, 2): (2, 1)} -> []
```

Reference solution in Python using breadth-first search:

```
def shortest_paths(graph):
    N = max(i for t in graph for i in t) + 1

    adj = [[] for _ in range(N)]
    for (i, j) in graph:
        adj[i].append(j)

    costs = [[] for _ in range(N)]
    costs[0].append((0, 0))

    queue0 = [((0, 0), 0)]
    queue1 = []
    while queue0:
        for ((c0, c1), i) in queue0:
            for j in adj[i]:

                (d0, d1) = graph[(i, j)]
                e0, e1 = c0 + d0, c1 + d1

                #dominated by or equal to an existing path
                if any((f0 <= e0) and (f1 <= e1) for f0, f1 in costs[j]):
                    continue

                #keep only non-dominated paths
                costs[j] = [(f0, f1) for (f0, f1) in costs[j] if (f0 < e0) or (f1 < e1)]
                costs[j].append((e0, e1))

                queue1.append(((e0, e1), j))

        queue0, queue1 = queue1, queue0
        del queue1[:]
    return costs[-1]
```

Comment: This seems a good question, but it's a bit hard to understand. Maybe a worked out example would help?

Comment: You should add the following example to ensure distinct results: {(0, 1): (0, 0), (1, 2): (0, 0), (0, 2): (0, 0)} -> [(0, 0)]

Comment: Do all edges increase current node id?

Comment: @l4m2 No, (i, j) and (j, i) can have different costs.

Comment: Then you should add such example

Comment: "These are the costs of paths which are optimal for some positive linear combination of the two component costs, or, equivalently, where you cannot decrease the first component of the cost without increasing the second component, and conversely." These two expressions conflict. Do I need to remove `(2,2)` from `{(0,3),(2,2),(3,0)}`?

Comment: @l4m2 Good point, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>248</s> <s>228</s> 211 bytes

```
fun Set<IntArray>.p(i:Int=0):Set<Pair<Int,Int>>
=if(i==maxOf{it[1]})setOf(0 to 0)else
filter{it[0]==i}.flatMap{p(it[1]).map{(a,b)->a+it[2]to b+it[3]}}.run{filter{(a,b)->all{(c,d)->a<c||b<d||a==c&&b==d}}}.toSet()
```

[try on playground](https://pl.kotl.in/b1YtFIqxI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 234 bytes

A port of [@Cactusroot's Kotlin answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/271481/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVPNToNAEE489ik2PTQ7kbZQamJqt0mPHnry2BCzwKIYpARWhQBP4qUm6sUn0kfwKRx-0tJtTZadnW93vvlmdnn9TBwecPNr3R-Gmxceh33r5-x9Yz8IR5IV90MiUilCNyHLKCJ5r0fIMw8Ij2OeJYSRZbWgiJJ22cy6Rox6TEFrN9CZoI_zDtJrCIcBoNUc4_Exy6Qbgo55ksWsWDqQ2aY_SWw0FF15DcWky2IcEze5p0quEyKnSvWNSITMf0s1FUXoXyjQrq0HIlVFxr6th7rVQFPRPa0z1s1tRSpNU27r-K5w1hUdB5C-hwApoHpPzVsaeZtYcOeeokvYgkSxH8ogpFEFjOTmRkiojET8jgLAx5P0hpffv67wSESTGR5Y10nW16G0LM2foWU61BsU1xp-YLHc96jPWDJ65BG9pVgMrlLAUxTloS4RJIKgHj-QIsYTOjDmw8gLuFxhCGcLTKfxNjLKHZ4ImmoZsAVNzznFfmZo8KJLaFm6Z-pKeRDkNlvgr0QdzQVG7SrMroKu0rlTFNncLQqaMuYMBhljLpRl2VT81trttrF_)

```scala
def p(s:Set[Array[Int]],i:Int=0):Set[(Int,Int)]={if(i==s.map(_(1)).max)Set((0,0))else s.filter(_(0)==i).flatMap(a=>p(s,a(1)).map{case(x,y)=>(x+a(2),y+a(3))}).filter{case(x,y)=>s.forall{b=>val(c,d)=(b(2),b(3));x<c||y<d||(x==c&&y==d)}}}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVPLTsMwEBQc-xVzQrYIJWmKhKoWiSMHThxRhdzEgaCQRolBIOiPwKVIwEfxNawfTVO3SJG9O17PzNrOx0-TiELEy9_9r_nsXiYKlyIvIZ-VLNMG51WF114PeBIFRF2LlwYTnOuAEQoX2jEMEJlvyAO3QMmAchpbKDQQfRHngeE4Pt5mGXS3UBLvZIk1SweKnfxO4shSdO1ZikGXJdomttpDT2uHyaHXvTVJUPxvq7HniPITD2qPdcOk7yhaH-umb39j7PkeGkVzuM6kd2jebW3fFY2h52MDCtcQJwqu35N9S_1sXkuR3DFKMTlDVeelKkpWaaCv5ldScT0pwm8Z5_z7UWVHp79776nMULFGqhGo6NoIXV-UajoNkI9AEb3TkNtVRmmgMT4l9JXk8wwsx2QCYug_iIrdMGqQomeudzDWupVFI03fVGlmoJ_lhZI17Qm55sh5u1AIdSkq145DYY0GumenQj8VEtFIMBFgxnXrTODQVOibmbmY3g0WjoZvqm8xtGq6JTpXURRU4zmxPzJLAqS0B2wl6MQ6dQJjJHh7Iy9jpDogh9RsgoMDwihK1-Urj4veomev6HNh5-XSzn8)

```scala
def p(set: Set[Array[Int]], i: Int = 0): Set[(Int, Int)] = {
  if (i == set.map(_(1)).max) Set((0, 0))
  else
    set
      .filter(_(0) == i)
      .flatMap(arr =>
        p(set, arr(1)).map { case (a, b) => (a + arr(2), b + arr(3)) }
      )
      .filter { case (a, b) =>
        set.forall { arr =>
          val (c, d) = (arr(2), arr(3))
          a < c || b < d || (a == c && b == d)
        }
      }
}
```